# Is there any hack I can use to prevent having to clean my gas stove so often?

Tags: cleaning, kitchen

Background: I often shallow-fry my food with high heat and a fair amount of oil. This means oil gets all over the stove and neighbouring walls. A good thing that I do (and worth sharing with everyone) is that I cover these walls with cling film. Remove and replace: really easy.

Is there anything similar that I can do which can do a similar job for my gas stove including the metal grills/frames?

(I'm not looking for answers like use less oil or use a lid on my pans, I do this sometimes, and it doesn't compliment the style of cooking at other times).

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use a grease screen?

Comment: @Paparazzi My thoughts exactly. You should add this as an answer. Here's a pic if you want to include it: https://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/BedBathandBeyond/2530512910649p

Comment: @Paparazzi I would have thought that disallowed  where the question says "no lids".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people use aluminium foil to cover the gas stove. This way, you can remove it every 7-15 days and you won't have to clean that much. It might be a bit tricky to put the foil the first times, but it gets easier with time and practice

Comment: This sounds good. I'm going to give it a try, though yes it sounds tricky to implement!

Comment: I just moved to a house with gas stove recently, and have to do it myself, I guess I will just cover everything, and then make holes for the burners

Comment: Make sure it is safe to put on your stove if it is electric stove. People have got electric shock after putting them.

Answer (score 2):

Not really a hack but effective. A splatter guard does not prevent shallow-fry of food with high heat and a fair amount of oil.  Water moiture can still escape and most of the fat splatters are caught.

[image]

Also a cone silicone product.

Comment: I've heard about these, seem fairly decent however I don't think it would be that useful for food where I may need to attend to it fairly often! I'd also have to clean this every time I use it so I reckon I don't really save that much cleaning in the end. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Cleaning a screen in the sink is as much work as clean a stove?

Comment: Yes, though cleaning a screen in a sink 7+ times per week rather than cleaning a stove once per week.

Comment: OK question was not really clear on that